# Error trying to generate dashed grid with latexmk and pdfluatex

Tags: compilation-error

Because when I start the following style \ tikzset {mygridstyle / .style = {dash pattern = on 5pt off 3.5pt on 7pt}}
with the "off" option instead of starting with the "on" option, does this not work?

Here's my MWE starting with "on":

```
\ documentclass {article}
\ usepackage {tikz}
\ tikzset {mygridstyle / .style = {dash pattern = on 5pt off 3.5pt on 7pt}}
\ begin {document}
\ begin {tikzpicture}
\ draw [mygridstyle] (0,0) grid (8,11);
\ end {tikzpicture}
\ end {document}
```

Here's my MWE with the "off" option:

```
\ documentclass {article}
\ usepackage {tikz}
\ tikzset {mygridstyle / .style = {dash pattern = off 5pt off 3.5pt on 7pt}}
\ begin {document}
\ begin {tikzpicture}
        \ draw [mygridstyle] (0,0) grid (8,11);
\ end {tikzpicture}
\ end {document}
```

When I try to run the command latexmk -pdflua -pvc MWE.tex
in the terminal shell script I get the following error message:

! Use of \ tikz @ scandashon does not match its definition.
 off 5pt off 3.5pt on 7pt
l.6 \ draw [mygridstyle]
                      (0,0) grid (8,11);
?

Comment: Could you post a compilable MWE, please? You cannot compile nothing using `\ documentclass...` and so on.

Comment: You need to start with `on`. On can be `0pt`.

Comment: I can compile with "on 5pt" or "on 0pt", this is indifferent to the MWE.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{mygridstyle/.style={dash pattern=on 0pt off 5pt on 5pt off 3.5pt on 7pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [mygridstyle] (0,0) grid (8,11);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` works. Your code has many excess spaces, e.g. after `\ `. . `\ documentclass {article}` is not valid.

Comment: Yes, @marmot. on 0pt works, but the question is how to get started with off 5pt, off 0pt or any other off <unit of measurement>.

Comment: `on 0pt off 5pt` does what `off 5pt` should do, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, on 0pt it works on 0pt 7off on 3.5pt as on 5pt 7off on 3.5pt, this would be an example. But off 0pt on 3.5pt 7off or off 5pt on 3.5pt 7off does not work.

Comment: Yes, because you need to start with `on`. `on 0pt off ...` does what `off ...` is intended to do.

Comment: I presume I understand the logic. I intend to start dashed with a gap (which is the very effect of "off") as I can not use off at the beginning of the style I used on 0pt. That makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dash patterns need to start with an `on`. If you want to start with an `off`, you can just add an `on 0pt` before that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{mygridstyle/.style={dash pattern=on 0pt off 5pt on 5pt off 3.5pt on 7pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [mygridstyle] (0,0) grid (8,11);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```